# How can I add a C# GUI to C++ code?

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface

I wrote C++ code in which are included some libraries and defined some functions plus the main. I am trying to add a GUI to this code in C#.

This code sends data (`double[]`) to a server. What I would make is create a graphic user interface using C#, that lets me to start sending data, clicking a button.

How could I make this?

I've tried to run the file .exe of the c++ project solution, but that doesn't work.

Comment: This invariably always works much, *much* better if you add C++ code to a C# project.  Bolting a GUI on top of code that was not written to support a GUI never works in practice.  Use pinvoke or a C++/CLI wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of ways to run C++ code from C#:

## COM

This is the canonical, good-bear way to do things, but I have a feeling this will be daunting at your level. Basically, you will expose your C++ classes as COM objects from your C++ project (dealing with converting between COM datatypes like `_bstr_t` for strings, et al). Then add this COM object as a reference in your C# project. This imposes the least pain on your C# code.

I suspect the biggest hurdle here is that you will need to understand how COM works, which is going to be pretty daunting if you don't already have experience in it.

## C-like DLL

This is probably much easier, if you don't need to call many functions. It's the same as how you call native winapi functions from C#. You export C-style functions from your C++ DLL, and import them in C#. Converting between datatypes is done via the marshalling system in C#. So in general this places the burden more on the C# code, less on the C++ code.

The catch here is that you can't export much C++ stuff. So for example you cannot export a function like:

```
void myFunction(std::string& s);
```

Because `std::string` is a template, and will cause havoc regarding memory management and will probably just lead to heap corruption.

## Rewrite in C#

If all you're doing is sending some data over a socket, then just write it in C#. For many things, C# is way faster than C++ for development, so it's probably worth looking into how much effort this would be.

Comment: 4th way: expose your C++ classes as CLR types by writing wrapper classes in C++/CLI. But if you can do this with a plain C interface then go for P/Invoke, as it's simpler.